# Selection of a property in a compartment shape

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dsl, dsl-tools

I have a problem with selecting a property on a compartmentshape of a dsl. What I want to do is:

I have a DSL with one compartmentshape which has many properties in one compartment. Each of this properties has a textfield which is used for saving c# code. I compile this code and add the error tasks to the error list. I added an event handler for the navigate event of the error task. Inside this handler, i would like to select the property of the compartmentshape which is responsible for the error. I tried many things, but didn't succeeded. This is my current selection logic:

```
public void Select(Rule rule)
{
  Library.Field ruleField = rule.Field as Library.Field;
  var ruleFieldPresentation = PresentationViewsSubject.GetPresentation(ruleField as ModelElement).FirstOrDefault() as ShapeElement;

  VSDiagramView activeDiagramView = Diagram.ActiveDiagramView as VSDiagramView;
  if (activeDiagramView != null)
  {
    var docView = activeDiagramView.DocView;
    activeDiagramView.Selection.Clear();
    docView.CurrentDiagram.ActiveDiagramView.Selection.Set(new DiagramItem(ruleFieldPresentation));
  }
}
```

The problem seems that an property of the compartmentshape doesn't have a presentationview, because I'm not able to get it.

I would be glad and very grateful if someone can helpe me with this problem.

Thank you 
Regards Manuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to open an error from the error list. There is a better solution than using the navigation event on an error. The better solution is to add a validation rule to the domain class and add the error with the context to the error list. Than the navigation to the property works out of the box.

```
context.LogError(errorDescription, "GAIN001RuleCompilationError", Field);
```